# Short squeeze of long term stock holding

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities

Does 50 % of the float being short indicate a short squeeze ? The stock also went up 25% today at the maximum , normally it is an inactive dividend play which is what I wanted. I put in a short at 10% gain on the day. Generally , what action is recommended if you are in an unintentional short squeeze ?

Comment: Cramer questioned the amount of short-interest on BGS

Comment: Your behavior is odd. If you care about dividends only, you hold the stock as long as you trust the company will continue/grow the dividend. Do you think that your dividend yield goes down when the price goes up? That's only for newly-bought shares. As a long-term stockholder, you will continue to get the dividend yield that you signed up for when you originally bought stock. (Assuming no dividend cut by company management).

Comment: I collected several years  dividends in a day . Then I will buy other dividend stocks or even buy back BGS at a much lower price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The size of the float being short does not indicate that a short squeeze is occurring.

Before you can consider today's price move to be a short squeeze, you have to scan the news to see if there is a fundamental  reason causing today's price move (earning release, analyst recommendation, etc.).

Determining whether it's a short squeeze or not is irrelevant to your action.  Your risk management should be based on price not labels.

Comment: Nothing in Yahoo financial news , stock is BGS.

Comment: Without and substantiative news, it smells like a short squeeze.

Comment: Twelve times normal volume.

Comment: Given that it closed at $34.03, IMHO, a lot of smart people booked gains from $39 to $41.66